# Okhttp3 creating Request Body Could not initialize class okhttp3.internal.Util

Tags: java, okhttp

```
RequestBody body = new FormBody.Builder().add("LicenseType", "").add("Password", password).add("RedirectToMyselfInCaseOfError", redirectToMyselfInCaseOfError ? "true" : "false").add("RememberMe", rememberMe ? "true" : "false").add("UserName", userName).build();
```

```
Exception
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class okhttp3.internal.Util
    at okhttp3.FormBody.<init>(FormBody.kt:32)
    at okhttp3.FormBody$Builder.build(FormBody.kt:120)
```

Application deployed on Glassfish 5.1
JDK 8

It is working when using Test Client in java.

Comment: More stack trace please? There might be another one above if that class failed to initialize repeatedly.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was resolved by using an older version of OKHTTP3 when it was implemented using java not kotlin.